# hide or show div based on customer logged in or not Magento 2

Tags: magento2

i want to have a text and a button  in home page when customer is not logged in and when he is logged in this block (div) should be hidden so how to proceed? any help please

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login 
}else{
 // customer not login 
}
```

Comment: i tried this but not working

Comment: share your code

Comment: <?php
$objectManagerlogin = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$baseurl = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl();
?>
<?php if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) :?>
    <div id="content">
        <?php echo  "hello" ;?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>

Comment: Try reversing the condition. Means add a ! (Not sign) before **`$customerSession->isLoggedIn()`**.